Validation if file is corrupted/broken
I have a problem with the implementation of one of my tasks, namely, I have a problem with implementing the code in Angular (TypeScript) that will validate whether a file (mainly png/jpg, but preferably any type) is not damaged in any way.
Unfortunatelly I cannot upload example of a damaged file beacuse StackOverflow correctly validate this case, but corrupted file is easy to create by opening png/jpg file as text (by visual studio code for example) and changing somet text.
At this moment I've tried to validate this case via (change) method in input type radio:
<input type="file" name="file" accept=".png, .jpg" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" required>

but I don't really know how to do it.
Thank you very much for any attempt to help

Arbitrary files may not have a way of validating them. You would need something like a hash to validate against.

I think we can render the image in a img tag, which has an onerror or (error) event, this can signal the invalid image and we can display an error message for the same.
TS:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  fileToUpload: any;
  imageUrl: any;
  invalid = false;
  handleFileInput(file: FileList) {
    this.invalid = false;
    this.fileToUpload = file.item(0);

    //Show image preview
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.imageUrl = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileToUpload);
  }
}

HTML:
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<input #Image type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" />
<img
  width="100%"
  *ngIf="imageUrl"
  [src]="imageUrl"
  class="image"
  (error)="invalid = true"
/>
<div *ngIf="invalid">The uploaded image is corrupted</div>

Stackblitz Demo
